# Table with Radiobuttons in Android

Tags: android

I am looking for something similar in android where I can add radiobuttons to each cells in Table and get their position. Does anyone has worked on it before, if you can share the sample code would be helpful. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361205/how-to-add-a-radio-group-to-radio-buttons-inside-of-a-table

Answer (score 0):

The following pseudocode should get you started:

```
//create a radio group

RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(context);                                                           
RadioGroup.LayoutParams rgParams = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(                                     
                            RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,                                                       
                            RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                                                      
rg.setLayoutParams(rgParams);

//add the radio group to the row. 
rowView.addView(rg);

//add radio buttons
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {

      RadioButton btn = new RadioButton(context);
      btn.setText(description[i]);

      //or save an object which will hold all information you need 
      btn.setTag(rowNumber); 
      btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                 Log.d(TAG, v.getTag());
          }
      });

      if (<some condition>) {
        btn.setChecked(true);
      }

      rg.addView(btn);
 }
```